# How to Fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null

Tags: javascript, html

it appears that when I call the if (test.href != "https://www.test.com") it gives me a null value, but I'm not exactly sure why, as I'm expecting it to return the URL

HTML

```
<p><a id="damn" href="https://www.test.com" target="_self">PC Install</a></p>
```

JS SCRIPT:

```
var test= document.getElementById("damn");
if (test.href != "https://www.test.com") {console.log(test)}
```

Comment: It appears that for my HTML code it just put the HTML, I'm not sure how to display it properly on overflow...     <p><a id="damn" href="https://www.test.com" target="_self">PC Install</a></p>

Comment: Hi Leroy,this is it `<p><a id="damn" href="https://www.test.com" target="_self">PC Install</a></p>`

Comment: try `test.getAttribute("href");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getAttribute`, and it works.

```js
var test = document.getElementById("damn");
if (test.getAttribute("href") != "https://www.test.com") {
  console.log(test)
}
```

```html
<p><a id="damn" href="https://www.test.com" target="_self">PC Install</a></p>
```

Comment: Hi Jack, it seems like I'm still getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Comment: It works in the snippet though - make sure your JS isn't running before your HTML.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I have to put my script at the end of my JS. That was probably my issue. I really appreciate the help, super thankful, I just joined stackoverflow, seems pretty handy!

Comment: No problem @JohnMckhay, if my answer fixed your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer to turn it green.

Answer (score 0):

try to reorder your code, and let your script after the 'a' tag.